# Juniper MX: NTP broadcast on two VRFs with the same addressing

Tags: juniper, ip-address, broadcast, juniper-mx, ntp

In Juniper, NTP broadcast is set at system level, so two VRFs cannot use the same addressing and use NTP broadcast at the same time. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Do you have a specific use case that requires NTP in broadcast mode? The best alternative may be to not use ntp broadcast.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know that most of the type the same configuration you want in the default instance exists in the same config stanza within `routing-instances`, in this case it's the other way around.

Addressing shouldn't matter as routing instances are separate routing tables.

You can enable broadcast NTP in a VRF with:

```
set system ntp broadcast 10.1.0.0 routing-instance-name VRFA
set system ntp broadcast 10.2.0.0 routing-instance-name VRFB
set system ntp broadcast 10.3.0.0 routing-instance-name VRFC
```